# Why does Time.now.today? return false in my Rails 4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, time, activesupport

It is 8:04PM in the Eastern Standard Time Zone (US) on February 5, 2016.

When I run this command

```
Time.now.today?
#=> false
```

it returns false.

Why, and how can I correct it? Thanks.

Details:

- Rails 4.0.0
- Ruby 2.2.1p85
- Mac OS X El Capitan

Comment: There is no such method as `Time#today?` in core Ruby.

Comment: interesting, this is in a rails project. So I'll add the tag.......Yep, just confirmed its a rails method. Will submit an issue on github, but I'm sure there's some configuration settings I can change to correct it for the time being

Comment: What does `Time.zone` return? How about `Date.today`?

Comment: So strange. `Date.today` returns "Fri, 05 Feb 2016", but `Time.zone` returns the expected `#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fbc0c1c58c0 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=nil> ` (UTC)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that often confuses people is that `Time.now` and `Time.current` are rather different objects.

`Time.now` returns Ruby library's Time class as it is. It returns the system time.

`Time.current` returns Time that's modified by Rails ActiveSupport library. It returns system time modified by Rails time_zone setting.

`today?` method is declared in `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, and it determines if the given object's time is today based on `Time.current`, not `Time.now`.

So if your `Time.now` and `Time.current` have different dates, calling `Time.now.today?` will return false.

If both represent the same day, `Time.now.today?` will return true.

`Time.current.today?` should always return true.

Except for some special cases, it'd be better to avoid `Time.now` and use `Time.current` all the time in Rails.

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue may be a time zone setting.  When you ran this at `8:04PM EST`, that is `1:04AM UTC`, your timezone appears to be set to `UTC` hence `1:04AM UTC` is tomorrow (`Feb 6, 2016`).

I would check your `config/application.rb` and try changing your timezone to `Eastern Time (US & Canada)`, It looks from your comment above it's currently set to `UTC` (default).

Running commands with (`Eastern Time (US & Canada)`:

```
Time.now
=> 2016-02-05 22:42:08 -0500
Time.now.today?
=> true
Date.today
=> Fri, 05 Feb 2016
Time.zone
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007f9a1bcffd20 @name="Eastern Time (US & Canada)", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: America/New_York>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1446357600>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: -18000,0,EST>>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1457852400>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: -18000,3600,EDT>>>>
```

When I run the same commands (`UTC` timezone):

Notice that `Time.now.in_time_zone` is actually tomorrow, thus `Time.now.today? => false`

```
Time.now
=> 2016-02-05 22:27:15 -0500
Time.now.today?
=> false
Time.now.in_time_zone
=> Sat, 06 Feb 2016 03:27:29 UTC +00:00
Date.today
=> Fri, 05 Feb 2016
Date.current.in_time_zone
=> Sat, 06 Feb 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
Time.zone
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fa19313f7e0 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: nil,nil,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: 0,0,UTC>>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your Rails app is configured (in config/application.rb or config/environments/*.rb) with

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

and your Mac is in EST, or conceivably vice versa. Setting the time zone of a Rails 4.1 app I have handy to `'UTC'` reproduces the problem for me.

If so, the discrepancy happened because, at the time you ran the command, the date was a day later in UTC than in your time zone.

Comment: well of course at the level of rails 4.0 my app isn't configured at all!

Comment: Confirmed (handily it is 8:24PM 2 days later), adding `config.time_zone = 'EST'` to application.rb prevents the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There no `#today?` method of `Time` in pure ruby, and it was introduced by `Rails`. Since Rails uses zone time model, I belive it returns `false` because current time have a gap to `UTC` (of course rails should be configured for `UTC`), to be properly sure that `#today?` will always return `true`, use `Time.zone` construction, so you will get:

```
Time.zone.now.today? # => true
```